# Trying to hash password in laravel by inputting new user in existing database

Tags: php, laravel

So im new to laravel and I want to, as the admin, add new users to the system but I want these new users to be added to the same database as the default one that created by `php artisan ui vue --auth` command. I edited the `register.blade.php` file made by the ***auth*** and added more fields. I am running into an error of `The acctyp field is required` as well ass `The gender field is required` whenever I want to add a new user whether through the register or my other blade.

This is the code:

**register.blade.php :**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="acctyp" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Account Type') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <select name="acctyp" id="acctype" class="form-control @error('acctyp') is-invalid @enderror" name="acctyp" value="{{ old('acctyp') }}" required autocomplete="acctyp" autofocus>
                                        <option value="">Choose Account...</option>
                                        <option value="">Admin</option>
                                        <option value="">Records</option>
                                        <option value="">H.O.D</option>
                                        <option value="">Teacher</option>
                                        <option value="">Student</option>
                                    </select>

                                    @error('acctyp')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="surname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Surname') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="surname" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="surname" value="{{ old('surname') }}" required autocomplete="surname" autofocus>

                                @error('surname')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="dob" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('D.O.B') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="dob" type="date" class="form-control @error('dob') is-invalid @enderror" name="dob" value="{{ old('dob') }}" required autocomplete="dob" autofocus>

                                @error('dob')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="gender" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Gender') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control @error('gender') is-invalid @enderror" name="gender" value="{{ old('gender') }}" required autocomplete="gender" autofocus>
                                    <option value="">Choose Gender...</option>
                                    <option value="">Female</option>
                                    <option value="">Male</option>
                                    <option value="">Other</option>
                                </select>

                                @error('acctyp')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="userid" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('User ID') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="userid" type="text" class="form-control @error('userid') is-invalid @enderror" name="userid" value="{{ old('userid') }}" required autocomplete="userid" autofocus>

                                @error('userid')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**create.blade.php** ->(this is in accounts folder)

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Add New User') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="acctyp" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Account Type') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <select name="acctyp" id="acctype" class="form-control @error('acctyp') is-invalid @enderror" name="acctyp" value="{{ old('acctyp') }}" required autocomplete="acctyp" autofocus>
                                        <option value="">Choose Account...</option>
                                        <option value="">Admin</option>
                                        <option value="">Records</option>
                                        <option value="">H.O.D</option>
                                        <option value="">Teacher</option>
                                        <option value="">Student</option>
                                    </select>

                                    @error('acctyp')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="surname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Surname') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="surname" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="surname" value="{{ old('surname') }}" required autocomplete="surname" autofocus>

                                @error('surname')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="dob" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('D.O.B') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="dob" type="date" class="form-control @error('dob') is-invalid @enderror" name="dob" value="{{ old('dob') }}" required autocomplete="dob" autofocus>

                                @error('dob')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="gender" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Gender') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control @error('gender') is-invalid @enderror" name="gender" value="{{ old('gender') }}" required autocomplete="gender" autofocus>
                                    <option value="">Choose Gender...</option>
                                    <option value="">Female</option>
                                    <option value="">Male</option>
                                    <option value="">Other</option>
                                </select>

                                @error('acctyp')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="userid" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('User ID') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="userid" type="text" class="form-control @error('userid') is-invalid @enderror" name="userid" value="{{ old('userid') }}" required autocomplete="userid" autofocus>

                                @error('userid')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**create_users_table :**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('acctyp');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('surname');
            $table->string('dob');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->string('userid');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

**create_accounts_table :**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateAccountsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('acctyp');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('surname');
            $table->string('dob');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->string('userid');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('accounts');
    }
}
```

**user model :**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'acctyp', 'name', 'surname', 'dob', 'gender', 'email', 'userid', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

**account model :**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Account extends Model
{
    //primary key
    protected $primaryKey = 'userid';
    // Indicating that the primary key is not a number.
    public $incrementing = false;
}
```

**register controller :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'acctyp' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'surname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'dob' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'gender' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'userid' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'acctyp' => $data['acctyp'],
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'surname' => $data['surname'],
            'dob' => $data['dob'],
            'gender' => $data['gender'],
            'userid' => $data['userid'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

**accounts controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Account;
use App\User;

class AccountsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $accounts = Account::all();
        return view('accounts.index')->with('accounts', $accounts);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('accounts.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'acctyp' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required',
            'surname' => 'required',
            'dob' => 'required',
            'gender' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'userid' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $account = new User;
        $account->acctyp = $request->input('acctyp');
        $account->name = $request->input('name');
        $account->surname = $request->input('surname');
        $account->dob = $request->input('dob');
        $account->gender = $request->input('gender');
        $account->email = $request->input('email');
        $account->userid = $request->input('userid');
        $account->password = $request->input('password');

        return redirect('/accounts')->with('success', 'New User Added!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

How can I achieve adding a new user and how can i fix the errors I'm getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `value`s for the `<option>` elements in your `<select>`s. Depending on what values you want/need either set them specifically:

```
<select name="acctyp" id="acctype" class="form-control @error('acctyp') is-invalid @enderror" name="acctyp" value="{{ old('acctyp') }}" required autocomplete="acctyp" autofocus>
  <option value="">Choose Account...</option>
  <option value="admin">Admin</option>
  <option value="records">Records</option>
  <option value="hod">H.O.D</option>
  <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
  <option value="student">Student</option>
</select>
```

or remove the `value=""` part to use the `<option>`'s text as value:

```
<select name="acctyp" id="acctype" class="form-control @error('acctyp') is-invalid @enderror" name="acctyp" value="{{ old('acctyp') }}" required autocomplete="acctyp" autofocus>
  <option value="">Choose Account...</option>
  <option>Admin</option>
  <option>Records</option>
  <option>H.O.D</option>
  <option>Teacher</option>
  <option>Student</option>
</select>
```

This will use Admin,Records,H.O.D.,Teacher,Student as values

Same goes for your `gender` select.

Comment: that fixed the error, but the values i input in the `create.blade.php ->(this is in accounts folder)` dont get saved in the database. how can i save them in the same database that the `register.blade.php` file saves too?